# Finding Solutions to the 24 Puzzle

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm refreshing my C++ by working through different problems and I decided to attempt a solution to the [24 Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_Game). Basically given 4 numbers, try to use the operators `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `^` to reach 24. However, for my solution I wanted to use a generic target number, operators, and number of input.

The speed is fine so I'm more concerned with C++ conventions, STL use, and clean code.

**Questions:**

1. Does this follow C++ standard conventions? I'm coming from Java so a lot of those habits often carry over into my C++.
2. Are there any better ways to make use of the STL here?
3. Is this code clean? How clear are the variable names? Right now this project is only a `*.cpp` file for main, a `*.hpp` file for utilities, and a CMake file, but I imaging better organization methods would be needed if this were to scale.

Where `flip_map( map )` returns a new map with keys and values swapped and `map_keys( map )` and `map_values( map )` return a new vector of the keys and values, respectively.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <map>
#include "Utilities.hpp"

typedef int Digit;

constexpr Digit numDigits{4};
constexpr Digit target{24};

typedef float (*Operator)(float, float);
typedef std::map<char, Operator> Operators;

// operators
float add(float a, float b) {return a+b;}
float subtract(float a, float b) {return a-b;}
float multiply(float a, float b) {return a*b;}
float divide(float a, float b) {return a/b;}
float power(float a, float b) {return powf(a,b);}

const Operators operators = {{'+', add}, {'-', subtract}, {'*', multiply}, {'/', divide}, {'^', power}};
const std::map<Operator, char> operators_inverse = flip_map(operators);

typedef std::array<Digit, numDigits> digits;
digits d;

void print_solution(const std::array<Digit, numDigits>& nums, std::vector<char> &ops) {
    std::string accum (numDigits-1, '(');
    for(unsigned i=0; i<numDigits-1; ++i) {
        accum += std::to_string(nums[i]);
        if (i!=0) accum += ')';
        accum += std::string(&ops[i], 1);
    }
    accum += std::to_string(nums[numDigits-1]);
    printf("%s\n",accum.c_str());
}

int main() {

    d = {8, 5, 6, 2};

    if(std::accumulate(d.begin(), d.end(), 0) == target) {
        std::vector<char> v(numDigits-1,'+');
        print_solution(d, v);
    }
    if(std::accumulate(d.begin(), d.end(), 1, multiply) == target) {
        std::vector<char> v(numDigits-1,'*');
        print_solution(d, v);
    }

    auto keys = map_keys(operators);
    auto ops = map_values(operators);
    std::sort(d.begin(), d.end());
    std::sort(ops.begin(), ops.end());
    do {
        do{
            float last = ops[0](d[0], d[1]);   // init with inner-most value

            for(unsigned i=1; i<numDigits-1; ++i) {  
                last = ops[i](d[i+1], last);
            }

            if(last == target) {
                std::vector<char> v;
                for(Operator o : ops) {
                    v.push_back(operators_inverse.at(o));
                }
                print_solution(d, v);
            }
        } while (std::next_permutation(d.begin(), d.end()));
    } while (std::next_permutation(ops.begin(), ops.end()));



    return 0;
}
```

and here is the `Utilities.hpp` source:

```
#ifndef INC_24_SOLVER_UTILITIES_HPP
#define INC_24_SOLVER_UTILITIES_HPP

#include "stddef.h"
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

// unused currently
template<size_t N, class T>
std::array<T, N> make_array(const T &v) {
    std::array<T,N> arr;
    arr.fill(v);
    return arr;
};

template<class T, class K>
std::map<T,K> flip_map(const std::map<K,T> &m) {
    std::map<T,K> flipped;
    for (auto i=m.begin(); i!=m.end(); ++i)
        flipped[i->second] = i->first;
    return flipped;
};

template<class T, class K>
std::vector<T> map_values(const std::map<K,T> &m) {
    std::vector<T> v;
    for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
        v.push_back(it->second);
    }
    return v;
};

template<class T, class K>
std::vector<K> map_keys(const std::map<K,T> &m) {
    std::vector<K> v;
    for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
        v.push_back(it->first);
    }
    return v;
};

#endif //INC_24_SOLVER_UTILITIES_HPP
```

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks! I added the include statements. Should I include the `Utilities.hpp` as well? I wasn't really looking for criticism on that part, but I'd be glad to add it if it helps.

Comment: That's probably a good idea, if it enables answerers to compile your code.  It really helps if we can test out changes we're proposing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you are interested in conventions and clean code, so here it goes:

1. Prefer `using` over `typedef`. It is easier to read and generally more C++-like.
2. Do not include C headers directly, and do not use quotation marks for system and standard library headers (looking at `#include "stddef.h"`). Use the headers that the C++ standard library provides (in this case, `#include <cstddef>`), and remember to put `std::` before the types and functions you use (i.e. `size_t` => `std::size_t`).
3. `#include` all necessary headers. Your code uses `printf`, but you never `#include <cstdio>` (and even then, you code should use `std::printf`).
4. `#include` headers in the order:

   1. `.h` file that corresponds to the current `.cpp` file
   2. headers from other parts of the same project/library
   3. header file from external libraries
   4. standard library  headers

   This ensures that each header file includes all necessary headers by itself.
5. Keep your spacing consistent. Notice the differences between

   ```
   for (auto i=m.begin(); i!=m.end(); ++i)
   ```

   and

   ```
   for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
   ```

   There is really no reason to save the whitespace, neither around the operators nor after the `for`; it only makes your code less readable.
6. Prefer the C++ equivalents to standard C functions. There is no reason to use `printf("%s\n", accum.c_str())` when `std::cout << accum.c_str()` does the job equally well but safer (what if you made a mistake in the `printf` format string?). There are times when `printf` is indeed the right choice, but simply printing a string usually isn't.
7. Use your `typedef`s. Why make a type called `digits` if you still pass a `const std::array<Digit, numDigits>& nums` (instead of a `const digits&`) to `print_solution`?
8. Declare variables in the smallest scope they are used in. Concretely, do not define variables in file scope unless there is a good reason to do so. `d`, for example, should live inside `main`.
9. Having `Digit` be an `int` is overkill. There are only 10 distinct digits, so the smallest type that can take 10 different values should suffice (usually, that would be `char` or `unsigned char`).
10. Single-character variable names are terrible. `d`, for example, should be called something like `original_digits` or `available_digits`.
11. You state that you want your program to be able to work with "a generic target number, operators, and number of input". Currently, your program can do none of that, because you hardcode everything. You should read your numbers and targets at least from standard input.
12. You can omit `return 0` in `main`; the compiler adds it automatically.
13. Do not use float for integer calculations (see Toby Speight's answer).

Answer (score 2):

One thing that strikes me as odd is that the inputs and targets are integers, but the code is working with `float` through the calculations.  I think it would be better to work solely with integer types (probably `unsigned long`), and reject partial results that are not representable.  It's okay to ignore such results, as if they form part of a correct solution, it can be re-ordered without fractional or negative intermediate results.

For example, with target of 5 and inputs of 3,6,10, then `(10/6)*3` would be ignored, but the program would still find `(10*3)/6`.

You'll probably need to write an integer equivalent of `powf` (though at a pinch, you could use `std::pow`, but you'll want to round to nearest rather than truncate the result).

A particular problem with using `float` is the test for success:

```
        if(last == target)
```

Because `last` is a float, `target` will be converted to float for the comparison, and any imprecision in the calculation could cause a valid solution to be rejected.

Comment: Where would the `modf` come into play?

Comment: Er, I meant `powf` - sorry!

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about ignoring solutions involving floating points. If I simply change to `unsigned long` type, then integer division could bring about wrong solutions with truncation. However, any check to see if the numbers divide evenly would add conditional branching every iteration.

Comment: I actually did something similar, but used a simple binary tree to represent the expression; each node of the tree had an `is_valid()` method as well as a `result()` and `to_string()`.  An alternative would be to reserve a value (e.g. `auto Invalid = 0uL;`) and have each operator check its arguments against that value, returning `Invalid` itself if given an invalid argument (similar to how floating-point NaNs propagate through calculations).  That is extra code you would need to write.